# match regular expression without capture

Tags: python, regex

I have some patterns I want to extract with regular expressions. As simplified examples, I have pieces of text below for which I want to extract the text without an underscore for the second field:

1. `main_opt.otherstuff` should return three fields: `"main"`, `"opt"`, `"otherstuff"`
2. `main.otherstuff` should return three fields: `"main"`, `""`, `"otherstuff"`

I can get this if I specify the regular expression to be `^([^_]+)_?([^.]+)?\\.(.+)$`. However, I wonder if I can change this pattern `_?([^.]+)?` where only one `?` is specified since they're part of the same subpattern.

I've tried `([^_]+)((?=_)[^.]+)?\\.(.+)$` and `([^_]+)((?:_)[^.]+)?\\.(.+)$` but they return "_opt" instead of "opt" for the second field. (I am using python's `re` package if that matters.)

Comment: Is `"main", "", "otherstuff"` the desired result or are you just reporting the result?

Comment: @dawg: yes, the three fields are my desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group them inside non-capturing groups `(?: ... )`, but it won't get prettier then your original solution:

```
^([^_]+)(?:_([^.]+))?\\.(.+)$
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQ6iO6/2)

Test on Python Console:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^([^_]+)(?:_([^.]+))?\.(.+)$', "main_opt.otherstuff")
[('main', 'opt', 'otherstuff')]
>>> re.findall(r'^([^_]+)(?:_([^.]+))?\.(.+)$', "main.otherstuff")
[('main', '', 'otherstuff')]
```

Comment: regex101 behavior isn't always the same than the real behavior. You should make your tests with the python console.

Comment: I still got same result... Added the results on console for completeness, thanks for feedback

Comment: I believe that (?:s)?he doesn't want an empty second capturing group, but perhaps I haven't well understand the requirements.

Comment: I quote him: "main.otherstuff should return three fields: "main", "", "otherstuff""

Comment: Ok, in this case you should exclude the dot in the first character class to make the pattern more performant (less backtracking)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: If `regex101` does the wrong thing with the Python flavor selected, that's a serious bug, and should be reported to them. Then again, this demo uses the PCRE flavor, which you shouldn't do for demoing Python regexps…

Comment: @abarnert You right, ill keep this in mind for next answers, in this case though final result is the same for both flavors, just updated to the correct one

Comment: @abarnert: regex101 has a python mode. I don't know if it uses pcre to do that, but it isn't the problem. The problem is that regex101 doesn't display defined capture groups that doesn't match. (however it seems to count it)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: You mean it gives false positive matches? Or just that there's no way to tell where the empty "red" match in this example's match 2 is supposed to fit in?

Comment: @abarnert: I mean that for example with `^([^_]+)(?:_([^.]+))?\.(.+)$` and `main.otherstuff`, python (and other implementations) displays an empty second capture group, when regex101 doesn't display it at all.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Right, it shows green "1." and orange "3." for Match 2, with nothing in between them, and no red "2." anywhere at all. That's what I was asking. At least for numbered capture groups it's pretty obvious from that display that group 2 didn't capture anything even though the match as a whole succeeded, so I don't think it's a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting might simplify the approach:

```
>>> re.split(r'_|\.', 'main_opt.otherstuff')
['main', 'opt', 'otherstuff']
>>> re.split(r'_|\.', 'main.otherstuff')
['main', 'otherstuff']
```

Comment: Why not, however this doesn't garanted the number of groups (less than 4, more than 1).

Comment: I ask the OP to clarify if he desires 3 groups in all cases. Maybe I am a knucklehead, but the post is not clear on that to me.

Comment: Like a lot of posts here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this more simply without regular expressions by just splitting twice.

```
mainopt, _, otherstuff = wholething.partition('.')
main, _, opt = mainopt.partition('_')
```

Here's what this will do for different inputs:

```
`"main_opt.otherstuff"` -> `"main"`, `"opt"`, `"otherstuff"`
`"main.otherstuff"` -> `"main"`, `""`, `"otherstuff"`
`"main_opt"` -> `"main"`, `"opt"`, `""`
```

You can change the order if you want a different precedence, or replace one or the other `partition` calls with `rpartition` if you want a different associativity (e.g., if the last example should give `""`, `""`, `"main_opt"`).